# node.js app works locally but crashes when deployed on heroku

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, npm

I've been spending the past few days trying to deploy my app on heroku with no luck. The app works perfectly locally and heroku is able to display the main landing page of my app, but as soon as I click on one of the links in the navbar it crashes. Below is the error log that I get:

```
2020-08-18T22:41:00.087725+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-08-18T22:41:01.392738+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-08-18T22:41:01.650382+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-08-18T22:41:02.631432+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-08-18T22:41:05.144391+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-18T22:41:05.144412+00:00 app[web.1]: > cinewatch@1.0.0 start /app
2020-08-18T22:41:05.144413+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2020-08-18T22:41:05.144413+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-18T22:41:05.462534+00:00 app[web.1]: Express started on port 20048; press Ctrl-C to terminate.
2020-08-18T22:41:05.586508+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-08-18T22:41:26.813493+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=cine-test.herokuapp.com request_id=8d9fa52f-f684-4184-8952-b52b872279e7 fwd="73.223.2.138" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=49ms status=304 bytes=152 protocol=https
2020-08-18T22:41:27.020721+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/style.css" host=cine-test.herokuapp.com request_id=b416deb5-d5b6-4e1d-856d-3806b8b4407b fwd="73.223.2.138" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=1650 protocol=https
2020-08-18T22:41:27.114408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo.png" host=cine-test.herokuapp.com request_id=f7fbd636-4d82-42b8-96b5-67cbaf099fcf fwd="73.223.2.138" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=10805 protocol=https
2020-08-18T22:41:27.316012+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/theatre2.jpg" host=cine-test.herokuapp.com request_id=71d193fa-b5ee-476c-adcc-d17f70d2097d fwd="73.223.2.138" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=116ms status=200 bytes=1594986 protocol=https
2020-08-18T22:41:27.321207+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/theatre3.jpg" host=cine-test.herokuapp.com request_id=3e0d1d33-5017-4e96-9430-461c8e68ee7d fwd="73.223.2.138" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=116ms status=200 bytes=1341680 protocol=https
2020-08-18T22:41:27.361564+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/theatre1.jpg" host=cine-test.herokuapp.com request_id=596e2c08-948e-499d-bff1-6cf00ce160d4 fwd="73.223.2.138" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=163ms status=200 bytes=3699945 protocol=https
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152538+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/routes/awards.routes.js:20
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152554+00:00 app[web.1]:                     throw(err);
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152555+00:00 app[web.1]:                     ^
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152555+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152557+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152557+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152558+00:00 app[web.1]:     --------------------
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152558+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152559+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152559+00:00 app[web.1]:     at PoolConnection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152560+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pool.getConnection (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152560+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pool.query (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:202:8)
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152561+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Query._callback (/app/routes/awards.routes.js:18:24)
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152561+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Query.Sequence.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152561+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:205:13
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152562+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Handshake.onConnect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:58:9)
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152562+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Handshake.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10) {
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152562+00:00 app[web.1]:   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152563+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152563+00:00 app[web.1]:   syscall: 'connect',
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152564+00:00 app[web.1]:   address: '127.0.0.1',
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152564+00:00 app[web.1]:   port: 3306,
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152565+00:00 app[web.1]:   fatal: true
2020-08-18T22:41:28.152565+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-08-18T22:41:28.163244+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-08-18T22:41:28.163621+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-08-18T22:41:28.166002+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! cinewatch@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
2020-08-18T22:41:28.166148+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-08-18T22:41:28.166314+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2020-08-18T22:41:28.166455+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the cinewatch@1.0.0 start script.
2020-08-18T22:41:28.166586+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-08-18T22:41:28.175255+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-18T22:41:28.175419+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-08-18T22:41:28.175496+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-08-18T22_41_28_168Z-debug.log
2020-08-18T22:41:28.224720+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-18T22:41:28.268272+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-08-18T22:41:28.270673+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-18T22:41:28.158365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/awards" host=cine-test.herokuapp.com request_id=fa9a6af8-7992-47d5-9857-8ad1133dc1c2 fwd="73.223.2.138" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Below is the file and folder structure:

```
- node_modules
- routes
    - example.routes.js
    - etc...
- static (contains css and js files)
- views
    - layouts
        - main.handlebars (main html layout of all pages)
    - partials
        - navbar.handlebars (navbar that appears in all pages)
    - example.handlebars
    - etc...
- .env
- .gitignore
- app.js
- dbcon.js
- package.json
- package-lock.json
```

app.js:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').config();
}

const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const mysql = require('./dbcon.js');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const moment = require('moment');

// constants
const port = process.env.PORT || 9716;
const app = express();

// set up handlebars
var hbs = exphbs.create({
    layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts'),
    defaultLayout:'main',
    partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/partials'),
    helpers: {
        moment: require('helper-moment'),
        getAge: function (dobString) {
            if(dobString == null) {
                return "Unknown";
            }
            let dob = moment(dobString);
            let now = moment().local();
            let age = moment.duration(now.diff(dob));
            return Math.floor(age.asYears());
        },
        yearOnly: function (dateString) {
            let date = moment(dateString).local();
            date.set({hours:0,minutes:0,seconds:0});
            return date.year();
        }
    }
});
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

//set up body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// set up file location for static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    let context = {
        message: "Welcome to CineWatch!"
    };
    res.render('home', context);
});

// routes
app.use('/genres', require('./routes/genres.routes.js'));
app.use('/actors', require('./routes/actors.routes.js'));
app.use('/genremovies', require('./routes/genremovies.routes.js'));
app.use('/actormovies', require('./routes/actormovies.routes.js'));
app.use('/movies', require('./routes/movies.routes.js'));
app.use('/theatres', require('./routes/theatres.routes.js'));
app.use('/awards', require('./routes/awards.routes.js'));
app.use('/theatresmovies', require('./routes/theatresmovies.routes.js'));

// start app
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Express started on port ' + port + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.')
});
```

dbcon.js (database url, name and password are contained in .env file):

```
var mysql  = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host     : process.env.DB_URL,
    user     : process.env.DB_NAME,
    password : process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database : process.env.DB_NAME,
    port     : '3306'
});
module.exports.pool = pool;
```

awards.routes.js (some details taken out):

```
const express = require('express')
    , mysql = require('../dbcon.js')
    , router = express.Router();

const getAllAwardsData = (res) => {
    mysql.pool.query('', (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }
        res.json({rows: rows});
    })
}

router.route('/')
    .get(function (req, res, next) {
        mysql.pool.query("", [], (err, rows2) => {
            mysql.pool.query("", [], (err, rows) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw(err);
                } else {
                    let context = {
                        data: rows,
                        data2: rows2
                    };
                    res.render('awards', context);
                }
            });
        });
    })
    .post(function (req, res, next) {
        var context = {};
        var {} = req.body;
        if () {
            mysql.pool.query(" () VALUES ()", [], function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    next(err);
                    return;
                }
                getAllAwardsData(res);
            });
        } else {
            mysql.pool.query(" () VALUES ()", [], function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    next(err);
                    return;
                }
                getAllAwardsData(res);
            });
        }
    })
    .delete(function (req, res, next) {
        var context = {};
        var {} = req.body;
        mysql.pool.query("", [], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
                return;
            }
            context.results = "Deleted row";
            res.send(context);
        });
    })
    .put(function (req, res, next) {
        var context = {};
        var {} = req.body;
        mysql.pool.query("", [], function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
                return;
            }
            context.results = "Updated row";
            res.send(context);
        });
    });

module.exports = router;
```

From what I gathered so far, the problem seems to stem from my database. Heroku is able to load up my home page without issues but when I tried to access the other pages (which all load and display data from my DB) it crashes. Appreciate everyone's help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the part that matters in the error

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

`127.0.0.1` is the hostname that refers to the current computer used to access it.

It means that you're trying to connect to a database that is hosted on the same machine running your NodeJS app. but Heroku dynos don't have MySQL installed on them.

To fix  it you need to go to your Heroku app's dashboard

1. Go to [Dashboard](https://dashboard.heroku.com) -> <your app> -> settings -> Config Vars
2. Click `Reveal Config Vars`
3. Fill in your environment variables (DB_URL, DB_NAME ...) with the appropriate values

PS: you need to have a MySQL database hosted somewhere, AFAIK Heroku doesn't provide MySQL databases, but they do provide [Postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql).

So you'll either need to change to Postgres or find a MySQL provider.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem and allowed me to access all the other pages without crashing.

Answer (score 0):

error message indicate to error in '/app/routes/awards.routes.js'
in line 20
there might be some thing wrong in making connection
can you put the code of it

Answer (score 0):

for me I was using a way old/outdated version of node/npm, and updated my package json to a more current version